# Fit a Gaussian curve with a neural network using Pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, curve-fitting

Suppose the following model :

```
import torch.nn as nn

class PGN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size):
        super(PGN, self).__init__()

        self.linear = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=input_size, out_features=128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=1)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)
```

I figure I have to modify the model to fit a 2-dimensional curve.

Is there a way to fit a Gaussian curve with mu=0 and sigma=0 using Pytorch? If so, can you show me?

Comment: What do you mean? A neural network can approximate an arbitrary function up to some precision so yes it can fit a Gaussian.

Comment: What is `num_actions` and what is `input_size`? You must provide details on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If your gaussian is 1D output should be of size one as well as input size (2 for 2-d data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neural network can approximate an arbitrary function of any number of parameters to a space of any dimension.

To fit a 2 dimensional curve your network should be fed with vectors of size 2, that is a vector of x and y coordinates. The output is a single value of size 1.

For training you must generate ground truth data, that is a mapping between coordinates (x and y) and the value (z). The loss function should compare this ground truth value with the estimate of your network.

If it is just a tutorial to learn Pytorch and not a real application, you can define a function that for a given x and y output the gaussian value according to your parameters.

Then during training you randomly choose a x and y and feed this to the networks then do backprop with the true value.

Comment: The spirit of StackOverflow is not to provide you the solution as is, you should at least try to learn how it works. There is lot of documentation on Internet and PyTorch forums. However, if you are stuck on a particular function or if you are facing bugs, sure we can help.

Comment: First you should learn the fundamental steps of neural nets (backprop, loss functions, ...), then how the framework works: how to define a network, test it, create input data and validate it. Try to begin with simple examples found online for instance.

Answer (score 1):

For a function `y = a*exp(-((x-b)^2)/2c^2)`,

Create this mathematical equation, for some values of `x`, (and `a`,`b`,`c`), get the outputs `y`. This will be your training set with `x` values as inputs and `y` values as output labels. Since this is not a linear equation, you will have to experiment with no of layers/neurons and other stuff, but it will give you a good enough approximation. For different values of `a`,`b`,`c`, generate your data for that and maybe try different things like adding those as inputs with `x`.